# How to link url or .html page link to CSS button

Tags: html, css

I have a "migrated.html" page in root directory. How do I add that link to this CSS style button?

```
<button onclick="#" <a href="migrated.html" class="glossy-button glossy-button--red"></a>Migrated</button>
```

The above html code didn't work for me.

Here is the link to the code set:

https://codepen.io/prateek-vishwas/pen/Rwwpzjo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why it has to be a button ? Why not use the normal "A" tag and style him like a button ?

```
<a href="migrated.html" class="glossy-button glossy-button--red">!!!Migrated!!! 
</a>
```

Works in your codepen - ijust moved the migrated text inside the tag

This will work even without javascript. 
Anyhow.the js to change the current url is

```
window.location = 'your url';

  <button onclick="window.location='migrated.html';"> 
   <a href="migrated.html" class="glossy-button glossy-button--red"></a>
   Migrated
   </button>
```

which also work in your pen

Comment: First solution worked perfectly for me. I have just started learning css 3 days ago. Still a lot to learn. Thank you for your help @thomas

Comment: Thomas Is it possible to remove underline from the button text/ hyperlink?

Comment: Yes it is :) With CSS  -> a{text-decoration:none;} will do this tiny trick :) Keep on lerning :)

Answer (score 1):

There are a few different ways to accomplish this.

But, from what I understand, it sounds like you just want an anchor `<a>` tag with a `href` attribute that is styled like this button.

You can simply just set the same class on the anchor tag that is on the button, so you should receive

`<a href = "url-to-ur-page" class = glossy-button glossy-button--red>Migrated</a>`